# How to determine programmatically whether an extension is disabled?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Can an extension's enabled/disabled status be determined using the Windows command line or some other method?

If an extension's settings are changed and those changes are recorded in the `settings.json` file and that extension is then disabled or uninstalled, those changes become 'dimmed out'. Perhaps there is a database entry somewhere that stores the dimmed status of an entry in the `settings.json`?

Comment: you can use this command line to list extensions.  But does not show whether disabled. `code --list-extensions  --show-versions`

Comment: I submitted this request in GitHub.

Request: Provide the ability to list extensions by all/enabled/disabled[link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112088)

Answer (score 1):

**From within your own TypeScript extension** you can use this:

```
const testedExtension =  vscode.extensions.getExtension("<author of the extension>.<name of the extension>");
if (typeof testedExtension !== "undefined") {
    if (testedExtension.isActive) {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage("The tested extension is active (ie enabled). :-)", {modal: true});
    }
    else {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage("The tested extension is NOT active (ie disabled). :-(", {modal: true});
    }
}
else {
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage("The tested extension was not found (ie not installed). :-( :-(", {modal: true});
}
```

Comment: `isActive` only indicates whether the extension has been activated - which sometimes doesn't happen until one of its commands has been triggered.  So that part of your code isn't telling us anything about the OP's question, which is about whether an extension is disabled.  Not active !== disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the extension's config to see if it has any of it's settings.

const isCppExtEnabled = cCppConfig.has(cCppSettingNames.autocomplete);

IsActive on the cpp extension returns false but isCppExtEnabled returns true

If I disable the extension then isCppExtEnabled is false